# Python get last month and year

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am trying to get last month and current year in the format: July 2016.

I have tried (but that didn't work) and it does not print July but the number:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print now.year, now.month(-1)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
last_month = now.month-1 if now.month > 1 else 12
last_year = now.year - 1
```

to get the month name you can use

```
"Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec".split()[last_month-1]
```

Comment: And if you want to print the name of the month, not just the number, as the OP asks?

Comment: Could you please put that in your code so it makes sense ? Thank you!

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Is there nothing nicer? Wouldn't `strftime()` work here?

Comment: print(last_month.strftime('%B %Y'))

Comment: @AkshatMahajan not really .. you cannot just -30 days ...what if its the 31'st day ... etc(too many edge cases) ... the easiest way is to just decrement by one and make sure its between 1 and 12

Comment: @pihentagyuakaJamesDoepp its not a datetime object anymore ... its just an integer ... (see previous comment)

Comment: @JoranBeasley you can also use `from calendar import month_abbr; month_name = month_abbr[last_month]`

Answer (score 39):

If you're manipulating dates then the [dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) library is always a great one to have handy for things the Python stdlib doesn't cover easily.

First, install the `dateutil` library if you haven't already:

```
pip install python-dateutil
```

Next:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

# Returns the same day of last month if possible otherwise end of month
# (eg: March 31st->29th Feb an July 31st->June 30th)
last_month = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=1)

# Create string of month name and year...
text = format(last_month, '%B %Y')
```

Gives you:

```
'July 2016'
```

Comment: dang good answer ... sometimes even i learn new things :P (I use dateutil alot but usually just the date parser)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution using Pandas which converts today to a monthly period and then subtracts one (month).  Converted to desired format using `strftime`.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

>>> (pd.Period(dt.datetime.now(), 'M') - 1).strftime('%B %Y')
u'July 2016'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

last_month = date.today().replace(day=1) - timedelta(1)             
last_month.strftime("%B %Y")
```

`date.today().replace(day=1)` gets the first day of current month, substracting 1 day will get last day of last month

Comment: use `date.today().replace(day=1) ` can replace current day to 1st day, just the first day of current month, then minus one day and you can get the last day of last month.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just the Python datetime library to achieve this.

Explanation:

- Replace day in today's date with 1, so you get date of first day of this month.
- Doing - timedelta(days=1) will give last day of previous month.
- format and use '%B %Y' to convert to required format.

```
import datetime as dt
format(dt.date.today().replace(day=1) - dt.timedelta(days=1), '%B %Y')
>>>'June-2019'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def subOneMonth(dt):
   day = dt.day
   res = dt.replace(day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days =1) 
   try:
     res.replace(day= day)
   except ValueError:
     pass
   return res

print subOneMonth(datetime.datetime(2016,07,11)).strftime('%d, %b %Y')
11, Jun 2016
print subOneMonth(datetime.datetime(2016,01,11)).strftime('%d, %b %Y')
11, Dec 2015
print subOneMonth(datetime.datetime(2016,3,31)).strftime('%d, %b %Y')
29, Feb 2016
```

Comment: Nice concept, but doesn't work in all cases: `subOneMonth(datetime.datetime(2016,3,31))`

Comment: Why the `while 1`? Seems to overly complicate things. Your `res` already points to the last day of the month if the `replace` fails.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
#Datetime: 1  month ago
datetime_to = datetime.now().replace(day=15) - timedelta(days=30 * 1) 
#Date    : 2  months ago
date_to     = date.today().replace(day=15)   - timedelta(days=30 * 2) 
#Date    : 12 months ago
date_to     = date.today().replace(day=15)   - timedelta(days=30 *12) 
#Accounting standards: 13 months ago of pervious day
date_ma = (date.today()-timedelta(1)).replace(day=15)-timedelta(days=30*13)
yyyymm = date_ma.strftime('%Y%m') #201909
yyyy = date_ma.strftime('%Y')     #2019

#Error Range Test
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time
import pandas as pd
for i in range(1,120):
    pdmon = (pd.Period(dt.datetime.now(), 'M')-i).strftime('%Y%m')
    wamon = (date.today().replace(day=15)-timedelta(days=30*i)).strftime('%Y%m')
    if pdmon != wamon:
        print('Incorrect %s months ago:%s,%s' % (i,pdmon,wamon))
        break
#Incorrect 37 months ago:201709,201710
```

Comment: Please consider adding a few lines of explaination instead of just pasting the code

Comment: @Yatin Can you see only just the code? Can't you see comments and examples?

Comment: Yes, I can see the comments but it is still not quite clear what you are trying to explain in your answer. A few lines of explanation would work like a charm to undo that! :)

Answer (score 0):

`import datetime as dt`

- .replace(day=1) replaces today's date with the first day of the month, simple
- subtracting timedelta(1) subtracts 1 day, giving the last day of the previous month
  `last_month = dt.datetime.today().replace(day=1) - dt.timedelta(1)`
- user wanted the word July, not the 6th month so updating %m to %B
  `last_month.strftime("%Y, %B")`